# Handling Imbalanced Data

Tags: data-science

I am unsure about when to use which approach while dealing with imbalanced data. I have the following questions:

1. According to my understanding, if the minority class is about 10% or lower compared to the total data, one should consider applying imbalanced data handling techniques. Is my understanding correct?
2. Most scikit-learn models have the `balanced` parameter, which can be set to true to add more weight to the minority class observations. Will this on its own be enough to handle the imbalance?
3. I have also come across undersampling/oversampling. Wouldn't performing either of the two alter the inherent nature of the data?

As for how I approached this problem in one of my projects, I created a custom function that checked multiple classification thresholds on each model I built to determine the (optimal) threshold by maximizing the F1 score. Compared with the baseline model (without changing the classification threshold) results, the results for the optimal threshold were better in accurately classifying the minority class. Is my approach appropriate in this situation?